# Changing Frequency of a Fourier Transformed signal

Tags: fourier-series, matlab, transformation

How can I change the frequency of a signal after taking its fourier transform? I am taking voice input from user in MATLAB and than I take its fourier transform to convert the signal in frequency domain. Now I want to change the multiply the frequency of the transformed signal inorder to change the pitch of the sound, but I don't know how to do it?

Any body help.

Answer (score 1):

just play the sound with a higher sample rate than the original